# Rerun jQuery function if focus is still on input when iframe reloads?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field which when focused fires a jQuery function to hide some content in the iframe, this works fine. But if the iframe content is reloaded/refreshed while the input field is still in focus the jQuery function will not fire again. Is it possible to rerun the jQuery below if the input is still in focus after iframe content is reloaded?

```
$('#_customize-input-checkin\\[message\\]').focus(function() {
            var $iframe = $("#customize-preview iframe").contents();
            $("#alert_check_in_notification_sent", $iframe).css("display", "block");
            $("#check-in-wrap", $iframe).css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: Suggest putting code in iframe page that calls a parent window function either directly or with postMessage API

Answer (score -1):

You can handle iframe onload event to execute the same logic. Try the following-

```
function exec(){
    var $iframe = $("#customize-preview iframe").contents();
    $("#alert_check_in_notification_sent", $iframe).css("display", "block");
    $("#check-in-wrap", $iframe).css("display", "none");
}

$('#_customize-input-checkin\\[message\\]').focus(function() {
    exec();
});

$("#customize-preview iframe").load(function(){
    if($('#_customize-input-checkin\\[message\\]').is(":focus"))    
        exec();
});
```

Comment: That's not how to add event listener to jQuery object. Will only register initial load using this approach also

Comment: @charlietfl this small example shows how load event executes everytime iframe loads - https://jsfiddle.net/npyz2ga6/

Comment: @joq3, did you try above approach?

Comment: Huh? neither of those domains will load in iframe due to iframe blockers

Comment: You are right but the debate is to see whether load event fires everytime or not. That seems to be firing as expected